# What's the difference between saying "not so much" and "no I don't"?

Tags: difference, responses

What's the difference between saying "not so much" and "no I don't"?

For example:

> Q: Do you like horror movies?

> A1: Not so much.

> A2: No I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything I've written below is related solely to the question:

> Q: Do you like horror movies?

---

> A2: No I don't.

Means that you actually **don't like** horror movies at all.

---

> A1: Not so much.

Means that you actually prefer some other types of movies but it's possible that there are some horror movies that you like.

---

Here's a link to Oxford dictionary regarding [not so much](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/not-so-much).